# Budgie - Lockscreen not working on 22.04

Tags: 22.04, budgie

On my Ubuntu 22.04 Budgie, my lock screen and hibernate are not working. I've Googled some other solutions without success.

Here some of the output:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ gnome-screensaver --debug
[gs_debug_init] gs-debug.c:106 (14:15:07):   Debugging enabled
[main] gnome-screensaver.c:86 (14:15:07):    initializing gnome-screensaver 3.6.1
[query_session_id] gs-listener-dbus.c:1471 (14:15:07):   Couldn't determine our own session id: No data available
[init_session_id] gs-listener-dbus.c:1518 (14:15:07):    Got session-id: (null)
[gs_fade_init] gs-fade.c:920 (14:15:07):     Fade type: 3
[set_status] gs-watcher-x11.c:346 (14:15:07):    GSWatcher: not active, ignoring status changes
[gs_manager_set_lock_enabled] gs-manager.c:163 (14:15:07):   GSManager: lock-enabled=1
[gs_watcher_set_active] gs-watcher-x11.c:277 (14:15:07):     turning watcher: ON
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:852 (14:15:07):     obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameAcquired destination=:1.149
[on_bg_changed] gs-manager.c:550 (14:15:07):     background changed
```

Comment: Please list what you have tried and any messages produced so that you are not given a solution you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

Remove GDM3 and gnome-shell-common

`sudo apt purge gdm3`

`sudo apt purge gnome-shell-common`

Font: https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/lock-screen-not-working-in-21-10/5466/11